# I am searching for a way to change the panel i am writing information on. Panelsname are build up by a pattern

Tags: delphi, variables

I probably have a very simple to fix problem, though I have no clue how to do it. I am pretty new to Delphi, which is why I have very little experience.
Below is the piece of code I want to simplify:

```
procedure TForm1.Asign();
    begin
      case TileValue[1,1] of
        0: Fx1y1.Color:=clBtnFace;
        1: Fx1y1.Color:=clBlue;
        2: Fx1y1.Color:=clMaroon;
      end;
      case TileValue[1,2] of
        0: Fx1y2.Color:=clBtnFace;
        1: Fx1y2.Color:=clBlue;
        2: Fx1y2.Color:=clMaroon;
      end;
      case TileValue[1,3] of
        0: Fx1y3.Color:=clBtnFace;
        1: Fx1y3.Color:=clBlue;
        2: Fx1y3.Color:=clMaroon;
      end;
    end;
```

The Fx1y1 is a panel while the x1 is coordinate as well as the y1 (Coordinates on a "4 in a row game"). I am trying to somehow replace the x and y coordinate in the panel name by another variable, so I can shorten the code. It should look something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Asign();
  var A,B:integer;
    begin
      for B:=1 to 6 do begin
      for A:=1 to 7(Because the 4 in a row playing field is 6 by 7) do begin
        case TileValue[A,B] of
          0: Fx{A}y{b}.Color:=clBtnFace;
          1: Fx{A}y{b}.Color:=clBlue;
          2: Fx{A}y{b}.Color:=clMaroon;
        end;
      end;
      end;
    end;
```

Is that even possible? If yes or no please tell me.

Comment: Put these panels in an array and index into the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you're asking for by using the Form's `FindComponent` function, which returns the component for the supplied name. Since that can be any component, you have to cast the result to `TPanel`. This will throw an exception if there is no component with the supplied name, or (possibly) if it is not a Panel. To further simplify the code I would also use an array for the colors.

```
procedure TForm1.Assign;
  const Colors: array[0..2] of TColor = (clBtnFace, clBlue, clMaroon);
  var   x,y: integer;
        Panel: TPanel;
begin
  for x := 1 to 7 do
    for y := 1 to 6 do
    begin
      Panel := TPanel(FindComponent('Fx' + x.ToString + 'y' + y.ToString));
      Panel.Color := Colors[TileValue[x,y]];
    end;
end;
```

As David mentioned, it would be cleaner to put the Panels in an array, and use that. From the code you showed it seems like you have created all the panels at design time, which is not required. It looks like you already have 42 panels, which is a lot to create manually, and if you wanted to make the field larger, it would become even more infeasible. That's why it's probably best to create the panels from code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreatePanels;
  Assign;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreatePanels;
  var x,y: integer;
begin
  for x := 1 to 7 do
    for y := 1 to 6 do
    begin
      Panels[x,y] := TPanel.Create(Self);
      Panels[x,y].Parent := Self;
      // set the position of the panel
      Panels[x,y].Left := 10 + (x-1)*50;
      Panels[x,y].Top := 10 + (y-1)*50;
      Panels[x,y].Width := 50;
      Panels[x,y].Height := 50;
      // make sure we can assign a non-default color
      Panels[x,y].ParentBackground := false;
      // do whatever else you want to do with the panel
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Assign;
  const Colors: array[0..2] of TColor = (clBtnFace, clBlue, clMaroon);
  var   x,y: integer;
begin
  for x := 1 to 7 do
    for y := 1 to 6 do
      Panels[x,y].Color := Colors[TileValue[x,y]];
end;
```

You would declare the array of Panels where-ever you declared `TileValue`. Not only makes this assigning the colors easier, you can also change appearance & dimensions of the playing field a lot more quickly.

Comment: Wow Thank you very much. Helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear! You can go ahead and accept the answer if it fully addresses your question!

Comment: I didn't know obn can do that. Here you go.